# What are the contents of ipconfig.txt file on Samsung i9070?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s, files

I've got the aforementioned phone, Samsung i9070. However, for some reason (after mucking around with various ROM's) wifi stopped working at all. Theoretically I can turn it on and off, but no networks can be found.

When flicking the wifi switch on, following log gets written to adb logcat:

```
E/WifiConfigStore( 2341): Error parsing configuration: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/WifiConfigStore( 2341): readNetworkHistory: No config file, revert to defaultjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/wifi/networkHistory.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/WifiConfigStore( 2341): ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets
D/wifi    ( 2341): setting scan oui 0x469e95f8
D/wifi    ( 2341): getting scan capabilities on interface[1] = 0x469e95f8
D/wifi    ( 2341): failed to get capabilities : -95
```

I'm guessing the missing /data/misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt file is the problem here (Or something's wrong with the radio, but I'd rather not try to reflash OEM's 4.1 yet, as it's a hassle installing recovery and cyanogen again), and other roms I tried do not have that file, it seems.

So, anybody that has that phone could please copy me the contents of that file?

Comment: Can you check if the WiFi MAC adress is still present?

Comment: @esQmo 

It seems only devices are:

Comment: lo       UP 
upnlink0 UP 1b:00:00:00:00:00
svnet0   UP a0:00:00:00:00:00
rmnet0   DOWN  
rmnet1   DOWN      
rmnet2   DOWN
sit0     DOWN
ip6tnl0  DOWN